# How do I prevent OrbitControls' autorotate from taking an elliptical path?

Tags: three.js

I'm using Three.js with the OrbitControls.js from mrdoob's repo. During the initial rendering of the scene I'm setting the `PerspectiveCamera`'s position to `camera.position.set(500, 1500, 2000);`. Then, when I'm done rendering all of my Meshes I start rotating the camera by calling `controls.autoRotate`. `controls` is defined as `controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);`. Now, my camera is moving in a pretty extreme ellipsis along the z- and x-axis. It's also continuously looking at the center point: `camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 1000));`. How do I get my camera to turn neat circles around my middle point `(0, 0, 1000)`?

Comment: (2) controls.center = vect, controls.target = obj. (1)Rotation will be fixed to parent object rotation.

Comment: Could you be a little more elaborate there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to fix orbit controls centered on some position:

```
`controls.center.set(0,0,0);` // to fixed pos / vector
```

controls autorotate will orbit around controls.center/target on zero Y axis. Radius of rotation is camera distance to controls.center.

If your radius on Y axis (updown) os not zero, check the controls parent object rotation (scene or other).

When you control camera with controls, camera position and rotation is set in each frame, you cannot change it by code. Will be immediately overwritten in next frame.

If you want to change camera view out of orbit controls.center, try to create second camera and switch in render.

Comment: That helped me along to the answer. It seems the API of OrbitControls has changed. I just had to set `controls.target.set(0, 0, 1000);` and it rotated as expected.

Comment: @Martin `controls.target` is a `Vector3`.